# Import Spacing (margin, padding etc) with SCSS in Bootstrap 5

Tags: sass, bootstrap-5

I'm probably missing something obvious here - I'm trying to compile my Bootstrap using SCSS, so I can just select the files I need. Everything working great until I get to the margin and padding classes (e.g. mt-0). I thought these were part of the utilities.scss but apparently not, and I can't seem to track them down. Am I missing an obvious include here?

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities";


// Optional
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/root";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/reboot";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/type";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/images";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/containers";
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/grid";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mapping for the margin and padding classes (e.g. mt-0) is in the _utilities.scss [1] file however it generates the classes using the utilities/_api.scss [2] so you'll need below the utilities import:

```
@import "../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/utilities/api";
```

References

[1] Utilities file (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/5f89ea3a0f9b56547eb03b98afcd189b89d7e5a6/scss/_utilities.scss)

[2] Utilities API file (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/5f89ea3a0f9b56547eb03b98afcd189b89d7e5a6/scss/_utilities.scss)

Answer (score 1):

I just recently had the same issue. Every class worked except classes for margin/padding.

Now (From bootstrap V5.0) `left` is replaced by `start` and `right` is replaced by `end`.

So change `mr-3` to `me-3`

[Here's why](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rtl/#approach)